# Referencing a variable set in one include file in another

Tags: php

One of those 'simple if you know the answer' questions...

Here is the code:

```
 <?php require_once('assets/includes/config.php'); ?>
 <?php require_once('assets/includes/functions.php'); ?>
```

Relevant contents of config.php...

```
$config = array(
    "admin" => array(
         "email" => "email@myaddress.com",
         "display" => "My Address"
    )
);
```

My question is whether I can reference the config variable in the second required file? 
What I have in functions.php is:

```
function send_admin_email($subject, $message) {
    //Send Administration Email 
    $to = $config["admin"]["email"];
    ...
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   }
```

And that doesn't seem to work. Is it because I can't see the variables set in config.php?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure you can. You may have to explicitly declare them as global though (inside the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use "global" as Jari suggested, but I personally would prefer to use the $GLOBALS superglobal to keep the scope of the variable clear:

```
function send_admin_email($subject, $message) {

    //Send Administration Email 
    $to = $GLOBALS["config"]["admin"]["email"];
    ...
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

Edit: replaced GLOBAL by GLOBALS

Comment: I like the idea of keeping the scope clear. NB: $GLOBAL in the code should be $GLOBALS. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Bring the global variable into current space:

```
function send_admin_email($subject, $message) {
    global $config ;


    //Send Administration Email 
    $to = $config["admin"]["email"];
    ...
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```